# How to use Subscriber Key in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api

I would like to know how to use subscriber key other than email address
in Data Extension. Basically, my use-case is I've added new Data Extension
field called LeadID and I want to use this as my new Subcriber Key instead of EmailAddress.

Hoping for a positive response.

Cheers,
Jhessie

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SFSE.

Subscriber Key can be whatever you want, but keep in mind, however, that it's how SFMC keeps track of subscriber status (as visible in All Subscribers).  You will run into issues if have multiple Subscriber Keys with the same email address.

Also, Subscriber Key is not the same as a Primary Key.  A primary key's only role is to define the uniqueness of a data extension row.

Comment: Many thanks for responding to my question. Basically, I want to use LeadID as my subscriber key in DE. Where should I configure this field to be my subscriber key instead of default email address?

Comment: If on your sendable DE, you map LeadID to Subscriber Key, that's what you'll have.  But, you've got to be consistent with it in all of your subscriber data.

Comment: Makes sense. But in soap API, is this something that can be done at DataExtension object? In my existing implementations, I've been using DataExtension's properties SendableSubscriberField and SendableDataExtensionField with EmailAddress type. I really want to understand how subscriber key works other than using email address in this context. I tried changing this to another field type, it works but I haven't received any email messages.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs  If on your sendable DE, you map LeadID to Subscriber Key, that's what you'll have. But, you've got to be consistent with it in all of your subscriber data. 
If the Lead is converted, then how do we identify the SFMC subscriber?